# adding downward arrow sign to lightning:help text

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Please let me know how to add downward arrow symbol to the Lightning:help text.
i know that i need to add something to the attribute 'iconName' in the below code,but what???

```
<lightning:helptext content="{!v.text}" iconName="utility:info" class="popover"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get all slds lightning icons
[SLDS icons](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/).

You can enter icon Names with following condition

**iconType:iconName**, Makesusre **iconType** is in lowercase.
Example iconName = 'standard:account'

So I add down icon in your code

```
<lightning:helptext content="{!v.text}" iconName="utility:down" class="popover"/>
```

Comment: yeah ...i think i got your point ,it was given in that link only,its utility:chevrondown ,i have to write.